# Are Logistic Model Trees robust to imbalanced datasets?

Tags: logistic, cart, unbalanced-classes, weka, data-preprocessing

I am trying out Logistic Model Trees (Weka implementation) with very imbalanced datasets. Is anyone aware of their robustness without the need of preprocessing steps (such as SMOTE)? My preliminary experiments suggest that SMOTE makes the LMTs perform worse than without any preprocessing step. What kind of specific approaches would you suggest to use in conjunction to Logistic Model Trees to address class imbalance?

Comment: Can you describe the method and how it compares to logistic regression?  Logistic regression works well with extreme imbalances.  If using a tree method and a proper accuracy scoring rule, all should be well except for the very much larger sample size requirement to pay for the price of flexibility of trees.

Comment: Basically theLMTs are a standard decision tree with LogitBoost regressions at the leaves. For building these regressions, LogitBoost is also applied at the intermediate nodes so that the children inherit the coefficients from the parent and adjust additional features.

Comment: The paper that describes LMTs is [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/publications/2005/LMT.pdf).

I forgot to ask: could you please provide some references to confirm that logistic regression works well with imbalanced datasets? I think I have read the opposite.

Comment: No references are needed  because logistic regression uses maximum likelihood and you can see this in the log likelihood function.  King has studied behavior in the extreme case and there is a minor problem, but not enough too worry about.  The paper you referenced uses a discontinuous improper accuracy scoring rule which makes the comparisons misleading, and the algorithm will require huge sample sizes to form stable, reliable trees.